# Equivalent of scala hashmap in fastutil

Tags: scala, fastutil

I want to use fastutill classes in my spark streaming application (scala). I am using hashmap instead but based on [Spark documentations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/tuning.html#memory-tuning) , they suggest use fastutill classes instead of hashmap..First, i wnat to know if these classes worth and then want to know what is the equvalent class in fast utill for hashmap.

Particulalry I am using a hashmap

HashMap[Key_Object, ArrayBuffer[Value_object]..I wnated to know what is the best collection in fastutill

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Object2ObjectOpenHashMap.java](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2ObjectOpenHashMap.html). It acts like a generic hashMap class. It's default hashing functions works okay IMO.

If you want to reduce hash-collisions or better performance, prefer [Object2ObjectOpenCustomHashMap](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2ObjectOpenCustomHashMap.html). You'll have to provide your context-specific custom hashing function when creating the hash-map.

Note that, FastUtil has plenty of other types that might work better for you, refer to their documentation which can be found [here](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/)